# Documents4j java library in Android App to convert Docx to Pdf

Tags: android-studio, converters, pdf-conversion, documents4j

I am trying to use  [Documents4j java library](https://documents4j.com/#/) in my Android App to convert Docx format document to PDF file but the output pdf file is damaged or corrupted.
The output pdf file is empty with 0 bytes.
I am using the below code to convert Docx to pdf.

```
    String uniqueString = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/meer_"  + uniqueString+".pdf");

    File inputWord = new File(input);

    try  {
        InputStream docxInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputWord);
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder().build();

        converter.convert(docxInputStream).as(DocumentType.DOCX).to(outputStream).as(DocumentType.PDF).execute();
        outputStream.close();
        System.out.println("success");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if(outputFile.exists()){
        openPdf(outputFile);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*documents4j* functions by delegating the conversion from the Java application to an instance of MS Word. This instance can run on a server which you can reach via HTTP(S) but the local converter will of course not work on Android which is unable to run MS Word.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer!